# Unintentional concatenation between list items

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was working with some lists until I realize a weird behavior. I forgot to put a comma between items of the list. Then I got this:

```
my_list = ['foo', 'bar' 'xpto', 'qux']
>>> ['foo', 'barxpto', 'qux']
```

It took so long for me to realize that I forgot to put the comma there because the program doesn't threw any errors. So, why this happened? Why python concatenate the list items instead throwing an exception?

Comment: This is expected string behavior and does not seem to be related to lists: `a = 'foo' 'bar'`.

Comment: It's explicitly mentioned in [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation) so "by design".